# ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.deleteCredential not doing anything

Tags: apex, namedcredentials, connect-api, externalcredentials

I am working with the ConnectApi namespace NamedCredentials class to create and delete Named/External credentials programatically.

Creation was easy enough but now I am struggling to delete. I am performing:

`ConnectApi.NamedCredentials.deleteCredential('myExternalCredential', 'BasicAuth', ConnectApi.CredentialPrincipalType.NamedPrincipal);`

Of which there is no return (no exception thrown). If I alter any of the parameters I get a NOT_FOUND exception implying that all of my parameters are adequately pointing to the correct External Credential.

For reference it is a custom external credential with a 'BasicAuth' NamedPrincipal (no parameters at the moment) and a Custom header called 'Authorization'. The org is a scratch org running api version 58.0.

I have tried:

- Performing this as-is with existing named and external credentials.
- Deleting the named credential manually before performing (in-case its existence blocked the deletion).
- Deleting the Custom Header manually before performing (in-case its existence blocked the deletion).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as the ConnectApi.NamedCredentials resources are limited due to it being fairly new.

Comment: Can you confirm that the user has `Customize Application` permission? Also, what is the release your org is on?

Comment: @Swetha I have now tried after giving my User the Customize Application permission (Still does nothing sadly). The api version of my org is 58.0

Comment: Did you find anything?